# Converting particle hair to flat strips

Tags: mesh, particles, hair, conversion

I have a particle hair system (specifically for a horse model) that I need to convert to faces for export to another program.

For resource use, I would like this to be one-polygon wide strips that sit flat to the surface of the parent model (either the face that hair was generated from or the closest surface point would be acceptable).

I can't however work out a reasonable way to achieve this. There's no single axis I can extrude hairs on because of the complex shape of the base model (and when converted to mesh, the hairs themselves do not seem to have local normals that orient to their parent surface in a way that would make it possible to use those), and I by no means claim to have a full understanding of all of Blender's myriad functions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strip could follow the hair particle.
You can try Particle Instance Modifier
Create a UV mapped strip mesh as shown bellow. Note the orientation in the world:

[image]

Then add the modifier and play with the setting starting with the ones shown bellow:

[image]

Apply the modifier to convert it to mesh with UV mapped strips.

Comment: I had a bit of an issue with the fact the hair particles somehow seem to be twisted, so some fibres were aligned well in the Y axis and some in the Z axis, but with some trickery I was able to bake both versions and use a weight map to combine the parts of each I wanted, and it's more or less managed what I need! Thanks!

Comment: I am glad the answer helped. There is another way to approach this issue by converting the hair particles to Curves and using Geometry Nodes to add the Mesh strips. This way you could go in Curve edit mode and tilt individual strips to your liking. If this task is recurring you should pursue this path.